# Time Series and statistics

Tags: statistics, time-series

Consider the time series:

$X(t) = 2 + 3t + Z(t) $

where $Z(t)$ are Gaussian white noises from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

1. Is $X(t)$ stationary - why or why not?
2. Is $Y(t) = X(t) - X(t-1)$ stationary, why or why not?
3. Let $V(t)= \frac{1}{2q+1}\sum_{j=-q}^q X(t-j)$.
   What is the mean and auto-covariance function of $V(t)$.

---

My approach is that: I know a stationary process is one in which the statistical properties of a given series are constant, such as constant mean, auto-covariance etc. I know that the expected value or mean of the noise component is zero. How do I compute the expectation of $X(t)$? How do I show the statistical properties are constant or not constant?

Comment: your previous questions show that you now the way to ask. would you fix the formulation of the current question?

Comment: For (1), ask yourself the following questions:

First, what is the expectation of X(t) for a given t?

Second, what does "stationary" mean?

Comment: @MikeWierzbicki I wonder if the editing and LaTEXing has changed the meaning of part 3 of the question.  Perhaps the sum was supposed to be $$V(t) = \frac{1}{2q+1}\sum_{j=-q}^q X(t-j)$$ to give the running average of $2q+1$ values.  The way it is written now $\sum X(t)-j$ makes $V(t)$ equal to $X(t)$, right?

Comment: The part 3 of the question has been edited, it actually is X (t-j)

Comment: @DilipSarwate Ah sorry, yes I think you're correct.  It was previously written as (Xt - j) and I didn't even think about whether it should be X(t)-j or X(t-j).  The latter makes much more sense.

Comment: @Probabilityman Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: Hi i am sorry i was away for a while. i know that a stationary process is one in which the statistical properties such as mean, co variance etc. will remain constant over time. I know that the expectation of zt(noise) is zero, i am not sure how i go about computing the expectation of the above series. Could someone help me proceed?

Comment: Hi could someone help me proceed with my question as i am stuck.

Comment: @Probabilityman: Instead of posting a new copy of your question, you should *edit the current one instead*. The "edit" button is on the lower left of the post. This "bumps" the question to the front page again, so you don't have to worry about whether people will see it. I have deleted your duplicate question and incorporated the change you made into this, the original version of the question.'

Comment: @ZevChonoles thank you for that. I am new to this forum so i am not aware of the rules here.

Comment: Sooo... In a nutshell, you know that $X(t)=2+3t+Z(t)$ and $E(Z(t))=0$ and you do not know how to deduce the value of $E(X(t))$. What course is this question, homework for?

Comment: I would like to answer your questions but would need your support. My first question: Do you mean *stationary* or also *quasi-stationary*?

Answer (score 2):

Let me take some time to answer this question, because I think many may ask this here and there, so we have good reference.

Let us consider the time series:

$X(t) = 2 + 3t + Z(t) $

where Z(t) are gaussian white noises from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

*Is $X(t)$ stationary?* No it is not.

*Why or why not?* If it would be *stationary* or *quasi-stationary* there would be a stable trajectory (in the most trivial case a stable point) where any state of $X$ would correlate to itself after the same period of time. In other words you have a closed stable trajectory (in the trivial case a fix point). In your case the system is linear instable and the trajectory linearly infinitly increasing. The fluctuation term does not matter, it just builds a tube around the trajectory. There is no state which you could correlalte to itself after certain time.

*Is $Y(t) = X(t) - X(t-1)$ stationary?* No it is not.

*Why or why not?* The arguments are similar the previous case, although you introduce in this case a one-step memory. So your system reminds one step a prior in time $(t-1)$ but this is not sufficient. Because it does not ensure a closed and stable trajectory where every state would correlate to itself after a certain period of time $\Delta t$, it only says that there exists a memory (simliar a Markov chain *first/second* order). Because of the memory there is certain co-variance but not constant variance (better said an autocovariance) over all states.

Let
$$V(t)= \frac{1}{2q+1}\sum_{j=-q}^q X(t-j)$$
*What is the mean and auto-covariance function of $V(t)$?*

Now here you allow an extent from $(t-1)$ and corresponding one step memory to the complete history of the system $(t-j)$ over all times from $-q$ ($q$-*past*) to $q$ ($q$-*now* or -*future*). This is the prerequisite that the system could be stationary, given a stability (convergence) against any *Gaussian* fluctuation. That means if you could show that every state correlates to itself you may conclude (quasi-)stionararity. The metrics for such correlation is the AUTO-covariance that means the covariance to itself. It tests like scan over your states ($[-p,p]$) and checks whether every state corelates to istlef after a certain period of time (*the period*). Intuitively said it multiplies every state with certain other state temporaly shifted and sums up by means. The general receipt is simple and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance) comprehensive as well, with the expectation value:

$$E[V_t] = \mu_t$$

you obtain autocovariance $C_{VV}(t,s)$ (attention index $V$ to $V$):

$$C_{VV}(t,s) = E[(V_t - \mu_t)(V_s - \mu_s)] = E[V_t V_s] - \mu_t \mu_s.\,$$

Using this cookbook you can build the mean and autocovariance of $V(t)$.

*Next*, your approach to fluctutation is correct.

*How do I compute the expectation of $X(t)$?* I am not sure which $X(t)$ you mean but the procedure to calculate the mean is basic stochastic see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) and denoted as above $E[X_t] = \mu_t$. However, you should reasonably check in advance whether your $X(t)$ can have a mean: if your system (like in 1) would grow for endless time, then building means out of your observations or equation would not make sense, except you will gain the information that there is no mean over infinity. So if you do not have a constant mean over infinity of *time* the trajectory can not be stable.

*How do I show the statastical properties are constant or not constant?* If you take your equations 1-3 and calculate according to receipt given above the mean and the autocovariance, and the result you obtain turns to be time invariant ($t$ vanishes, independent of time, constant) then you have it.

For your assistance also find here the conditions for stability when calculating the autocovariance [>>>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance#Stationarity)

Hope this helps you with all references and clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The series is not stationary because there is a linear trend which means that the process average is changing with time.

Y(t) is just Z(t)-Z(t-1) .  So the linear trend is remove.  It now has mean 0 because Z has mean 0.  Z is stationary because it is Gaussian white noise.

Expressed in terms of past Ys Y(t)= Y(t-1)-Y(t-2)+Y(t-3)-...+Z(t).  It has a constant mean but to be statioanry it must have a constant variance too.  Does it?

V(t) = ∑$_j$ Z(t-j)/(2q-1)  +(2q+1)(2+3t)/(2q-1) -  ∑$_j$ j/(2q-1) But the sum of j from -q to q is 0 so we get

V(t) = ∑$_j$ Z(t-j)/(2q-1) + (2q+1)(2+3t)/2q-1).  From this you should be able to compute the mean function and autocovariance function+

Answer (score 1):

1. $X_t$ is non-stationary at least because its Expectation is not equal to constant. Remember, for covariance stationarity you should have first two moments time invariant. Obviously, $E(X_t) = 2+3E(t)+E(Z_t) = 2+3t+0=2+3t$. The first moment is time dependent, thus non-stationary.

2.It is stationary because the deterministic time trend is removed while differencing. $X_t - X_{t-1} = 2-2+3t-3t+3+Z_t-Z_{t-1} = 3+Z_t - Z_{t-1}$. Define $\Delta{X_t} = X_t - X_{t-1} = 3+\Delta{Z_t} $. Obviously, $E(\Delta{X_t}) = E(\Delta{Z_t}) +3 = 3$. Moreover, $Var(\Delta{X_t}) = 2*Var(Z_t) = 2$. The higher moments are not important for covariance stationarity. However, because u have the difference of a Gaussian process in the RHS which itself is a Gaussian, then higher moments are also stable and the process in fact is strict sense stationary.

3.I can think of the third one if you are still interested.

Best of Luck.